# Handlebars JS passing parent array into partial as parameter

Tags: layout, partial, express-handlebars

I'm trying to pass an array from the parent context into a partial as a parameter. I've read numerous SO articles and tried all the suggestions and so far I can't get it to work. The best I've gotten so far is the the array shows in the partial as [object Object]. That's the closest I've gotten :-(

In my parent layout I have...

```
{{> dropdown dd-id='appId' dd-text='App' dd-options=this.app }}
```

`app` is set to an array of objects like: [{ "id": "blah...", "text": "blether..." }]. It has only 1 line in the array.

In the partial is...

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
    id="{{ dd-id }}" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ dd-text }}
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        {{#each dd-options }}
            <a class="dropdown-item" id="{{ id }}">{{ text }}</a>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
```

In the parent rendered page, the dropdown looks like a Bootstrap button dropdown, so that's good, but the options shows...

`[object Object]` instead of the single option row with id and text that I need it to show.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for sharing your expertise! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well and it seems handlebars.js doesn't support sending arrays (or objects) to partials using named parameters. See this issue:

https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1058